# Calculations in media query statements

Tags: css, less

In LESS, I have

`@logo-width: @logo-height * @aspect-logo;`

Which, when used as a variable, usually yields a reasonable number

```
width: @logo-width;
>> width: 299px;
```

However, when I use the variable in a media query, it's interpreted as a string instead:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: @logo-width) {
>> @media only screen and (min-width: 80px * 560/150) {
```

How can this behavior be prevented?

Comment: Arithmetic expression in `@media` quires require parens regardless of the [`--strict-math`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math) option. I.e. should be either `@media only screen and (min-width: (@logo-width))` *Or* `@logo-width: (@logo-height * @aspect-logo);`

Comment: Surrounding it in parentheses did indeed fix the problem. Copy your comment to an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that exactly the same Q/A already exist here at SO... I just can't find it quickly for some reason (so I'd rather prefer to vote for closing as a duplicate... if/when I'll find one).

Comment: Well, if I couldn't find it and you can't find it, others won't be able to find it either, giving this one legitimate utility.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic expressions in `@media` query statements require parens regardless of the [`--strict-math` option](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math). I.e. for your snippet it should be either:

```
@logo-width: @logo-height * @aspect-logo;

@media only screen and (min-width: (@logo-width)) {
    // ...
}
```

or:

```
@logo-width: (@logo-height * @aspect-logo);

@media only screen and (min-width: @logo-width) {
    // ...
}
```